# Using the "Haunted One" background outside of the Curse of Strahd

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, background, curse-of-strahd

It is my first time creating a character. Can the "Haunted One" background from Curse of Strahd be used outside of the Curse of Strahd storyline?

Comment: Is this for Adventurer's League, or a non-AL home game?

Answer (score 16):

## Yes

This background was published in the Curse of Strahd adventure, but was also released in a [free pdf](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/CharacterBackground_HauntedOne.pdf) for use in other campaigns.

However, as with all character decisions, your DM has the final say on this, so ask them to be sure.